# Which database to use in a cordova/ionic 2 app in order to be fully multi-platform?

Tags: android, sqlite, angular, cordova, ionic2

I'm building this app and it must be available on mobile AND desktop browser.

On mobile it's easy to choose SQLite, but the cordova sqlite plugin still doesn't support browser. Ionic Local Storage doesn't support data more complex than key-value pair and data could be stored in volatile locations. Pouch/Couch db seems not well supported and works bad with multiple clients.

There is a database solution that can be common to all platform or data storage must be implemented with different solutions on different platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to manage a database-like complex json data could be using the provided LocalStorage converting and turning back data, as you need it, like tommerton suggest [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/store-objects-in-localstorage/44788/2)
Quote:

> use the Storage object and Sqlstorage as found in the api of Ionic2
>
> import { Storage, SqlStorage } from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
>   this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
>
> this.storage.get('questionnaires').then((data) => 
>   { if (data != null)
>   this.questionnaires = JSON.parse(data);
>   else
>   this.loadDefaultQuestions();
>
> And to store Objects, use
>   JSON.stringify(myObject) to store and JSON.parse(...) to turn back

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) with [an adapter](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-lawnchair-adapter) for [the native SQLite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) for mobile and then let it fallback to WebSQL or IndexedDB for browser.

Although the underlying storage mechanism maybe be different for mobile vs browser, Lawnchair gives you a consistent API which is what matters.

Comment: Not bad! The last important update dates back to 3 years ago https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair. This scares me a bit, but, if you're suggesting it, I imagine it is still a good product.